# If an unused function parameter is a pointer-to-function, is a definition required for its actual argument?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is the following a complete program, according to C++ standard?

```
 void foo();
 void bar( void(*)() ) {}
 int main() { bar(foo); }
```

MSVC14 builds it successfully if Whole Program Optimization is off, but gives an error "unresolved external symbol void __cdecl foo(void)" if Link Time Code Generation is turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's *odr-use*, so you need a definition for `foo`.

Otherwise what "value" should the function pointer hold? Where is `foo` in memory?

The definition triggers it being given an address, and you don't have one.

Comment: To add to this answer: you see an effect of undefined behavior: your program behaving differently depending on luck. I assume that with Whole Program Optimization turned off, `bar` is inlined and removed as no-op before linking, so it never asks linker for `foo` address. When it is on, it defers that kind of optimisations until linking stage. In other situations (definition of bar in another source file) it can trigger that error in every case.

Comment: Actually, w/o whole program optimization everything worked fine even when bar was not no-op (but parameter was unused - in the real program the parameter was used for template argument deduction).